# Debezium MySQL Connector- io.debezium.text.ParsingException

Tags: apache-kafka, debezium

Debezium stopped working right after I added TRIGGERS on my MySQL Tables.

This is what i got on the connector logs

```
Jun 29 16:29:24 log.gxapp-crm.com sh[4827]: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: no viable alternative at input 'CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` TRIGGER `gxapp_customer_db.BCAVAActivationApprovedReports_AI`                                                                 AFTER INSERT                                                                ON `BCAVAActivationApprovedReports`                                                              FOR EACH ROW                                                                 BEGIN                                                                DECLARE has_error BOOLEAN DEFAULT 0;                                                             DECLARE duplicate_key CONDITION FOR 1062;                                              DECLARE foreign_key_violated CONDITION FOR 1216;
DECLARE revision_inc INT'
Jun 29 16:29:24 log.gxapp-crm.com sh[4827]: at io.debezium.connector.mysql.AbstractReader.wrap(AbstractReader.java:230)
Jun 29 16:29:24 log.gxapp-crm.com sh[4827]: at io.debezium.connector.mysql.AbstractReader.failed(AbstractReader.java:208)
Jun 29 16:29:24 log.gxapp-crm.com sh[4827]: at io.debezium.connector.mysql.BinlogReader.handleEvent(BinlogReader.java:508)
Jun 29 16:29:24 log.gxapp-crm.com sh[4827]: at com.github.shyiko.mysql.binlog.BinaryLogClient.notifyEventListeners(BinaryLogClient.java:1095)
Jun 29 16:29:24 log.gxapp-crm.com sh[4827]: at com.github.shyiko.mysql.binlog.BinaryLogClient.listenForEventPackets(BinaryLogClient.java:943)
Jun 29 16:29:24 log.gxapp-crm.com sh[4827]: at com.github.shyiko.mysql.binlog.BinaryLogClient.connect(BinaryLogClient.java:580)
Jun 29 16:29:24 log.gxapp-crm.com sh[4827]: at com.github.shyiko.mysql.binlog.BinaryLogClient$7.run(BinaryLogClient.java:825)
Jun 29 16:29:24 log.gxapp-crm.com sh[4827]: at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Jun 29 16:29:24 log.gxapp-crm.com sh[4827]: Caused by: io.debezium.text.ParsingException: no viable alternative at input 'CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` TRIGGER `gxapp_customer_db.BCAVAActivationApprovedReports_AI`                                                  AFTER INSERT                                                                ON `BCAVAActivationApprovedReports`                                                               FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DECLARE has_error BOOLEAN DEFAULT 0;                                                              DECLARE duplicate_key CONDITION FOR 1062;                                                                 DECLARE foreign_key_violated CONDITION FOR 1216;                                                                 DECLARE revision_inc INT'
```

I tried to delete the connectors and added it back.

Does this have anything to do with the Trigger function ? Is it not yet supported by Debezium ?

Comment: What version is this? There was a fix related to CREATE TRIGGER statements just in this week's release of Debezium 0.10.0.Beta2. If you still see the issue with this version, please file an issue with the DDL statement in our [bug tracker](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/). Thanks!

Comment: @Gunnar how can I get the Debezium 0.10.0.Beta2 source ? I can't find it in the official website. Thx!

Comment: The source code is [here](https://github.com/debezium/debezium/tree/v0.10.0.Beta2), but you also can git the binaries from Maven Central.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't very clear, what I meant is the .jar files where I put in the "plugin.path" for kafka connect ? I'm new at this CDC apps. I'm not sure what is it called, plugin connectors? @Gunnar

Comment: For each connector (MySQL, Postgres etc.) one "connector archive" is deployed to Maven Central, e.g. [here](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/debezium/debezium-connector-mysql/0.10.0.Beta2/) for MyQL. They contain the actual connector itself and all its dependencies. Extract the contents of that archive to the plugin path of Kafka Connect.

Comment: https://medium.com/groww-engineering/moving-from-hibernate-envers-to-debezium-bae4856c0e1b

Comment: I have a similar issue https://stackoverflow.com/q/64372783/958373